# Working with multiple schemas on one server?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have one MySQL server with multiple schemas and it looks something like this:

-app_metadata [database]

- users [table]
- app_data [table]

-site1 [database]

- tableA [table]
- tableB [table]

There is multiple sites (site1, site2.. site32) and there are new sites being added periodically but the structure of all sites are the same, they all have table A and table B that that can be represented by identical models in flask-SQLalchemy.

Retrieving information depending on what site the user is interested in is quite simple with a query (not actual code but the idea is there):

```
user_selection = site3
query = f'SELECT * FROM `{user_selection}`.tableA;'
```

I'm not that familiar with flask-sqlalchemy and I have a hard time figuring out how can I translate this so that the URI is dynamically switch (based on the site selection).

I can do bindings for the app_metadata database as follows (I assume, not really the issue):

```
class User(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'app_metadata'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
```

The problem is how do I connect to the second database (pretty much on the go) based on the users choice and change the bind key inside the table classes.

```
class TableA(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = *users_choice*
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ....

class TableB(db.Model):
        __bind_key__ = *users_choice*
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        ....
```

I can't really change the structure of the database but obviously I can play with the code.

Comment: My first reaction to seeing this Q is --> this is easily solvable by changing your application design. It's highly uncommon to use multiple databases for a single application – where the db's purpose is to serve that application alone. So your best choice is to revise your app design and use a single db. Now, you may want to isolate the tables in a logical way --> for that, I'd recommend different schemas (within the same db). The result of which, you will still need to perform separate db connections per module/schema. _Does this make sense? If yes, I can provide further on how to execute._

Comment: Also, are you using `flask_sqlalchemy` or regular `sqlalchemy`? _(I'd recommend using the non-flask version, since your task is non-trivial)_

Comment: @YaakovBressler Yes for now i'm using flask_sqlalchemy. Unfortunately db side is more or less set in stone and I do need the data depending on the site the user interested in. 

The idea that your comment gave me is: run an initial flask app1 that is connected to one db(metadata), and then an app2(app within an app) that will be initiated after the user made hes site selection and will be connected correct db(site db).
I'm fairly inexperience with my current stack and will most likely use a duct tape solution for now (binding db manually), until I figure a more elegant way.

Comment: I ended up using flask_sqlalchemy for my static app databases, then generated another engine with regular sqlalchemy once the user has made a selection. This hybrid approach is probably not the best solution and will have to eventually migrate everything to regular sqlalchemy.